# how to detect timezone it is opened for my web application on frontend / backend?

Tags: html, http, web-applications

I am designing a web application which relies on the time information, so use new Date() a lot, normally I would assume this application is opened in the same timezone (in default UK) however if the application is opened in a different timezone (US or CHINA), the logic of application will be damaged, so how can my web application (front end such as HTML5 or backend in node.js) detect the timezone it is being opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I have found is using a GEOIP lookup.

IP addresses are not 100% fool-proof, but 99% of the time you can get the users general area, which would be easily good enough for the timezone.

Also, the are a lot of places that provide this service for free if the number is not too large.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript’s Date object relies on the end user’s computer’s clock having the correct time settings.

You could ask the user to share their location with you, using [the Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation), and calculate their time zone from that. But the user can choose to not share their location with you.